# Jenkins is showing "zombie" pipeline runs after restart - how to purge?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

After restarting our Jenkins 2.107.2 instance, it shows many previously finished pipeline runs in the "master" section of the homepage, with a partly-completed progress bar.

When looking at the console log for these runs, they were completed days ago (long before the restart), but are showing a "resuming" message afterwards.

```
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
Resuming build at Tue May 01 06:02:42 PDT 2018 after Jenkins restart
Resuming build at Thu May 03 16:11:45 PDT 2018 after Jenkins restart
```

How can I purge these old runs from Jenkins (where does Jenkins keep the state for these runs)? I have hundreds of them; stop/kill doesn't remove them either.

I see this in the run's build.xml file - is that what's causing it?

```
 <completed>false</completed>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-50199 seemed to be the root cause.
After updating the pipeline plugins (latest "stable" versions as of 2018-05-07), the zombie runs disappeared and all is good again.